# render a view to the client with json request

Tags: ajax, json, django, view

I come back with this with new question and more clear description, I hope, because I made a lot of changes but i havent found a working solution yet. To start from the beginning I have a view which whenever I push a button I want to return the rendered view from another view.

@csrf_exempt
def main(request):

```
menu_beer = Food.objects.filter(category=4)
menu_crepe = Food.objects.filter(category=2)
menu_club = Food.objects.filter(category=1)
menu_spaggetti = Food.objects.filter(category=8)
menu_burgers = Food.objects.filter(category=11)
menu_hotdog = Food.objects.filter(category=1)
menu_salads = Food.objects.filter(category=7)
menu_toast = Food.objects.filter(category=3)
menu_dessert = Food.objects.filter(category=6)
menu_coffee = Food.objects.filter(category=9)
menu_soda = Food.objects.filter(category=5)
menu_food = Food.objects.filter(category=1)

menu_offer = Offer.objects.all()
obj={}
print "request ajax------------------------"
if request.is_ajax():
    print "inside ajax\/\/\//\/\/\/"
    sItem=request.GET.get('itemId')
    print "GET itemId="+sItem
    if sItem is not None:
        getobject=Food.objects.get(id=int(sItem))
        print getobject
        obj['id']=getobject.id
        obj['title']=getobject.title
        print "{}= "+str(obj)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(obj), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        print "ERRRRRRR"

return render(request,'main.html',{'view_title':"Menu",
                                   'menu_crepe':menu_crepe,
                                   'menu_club':menu_club,
                                   'menu_spaghetti':menu_spaggetti,
                                   'menu_burgers':menu_burgers,
                                   'menu_hotdog':menu_hotdog,
                                   'menu_salads':menu_salads,
                                   'menu_toast':menu_toast,
                                   'menu_dessert':menu_dessert,
                                   'menu_coffee':menu_coffee,
                                   'menu_soda':menu_soda,
                                   'menu_beer':menu_beer,
                                   'menu_offer':menu_offer,

                               })
```

def profile(request):
    return render(request,'profile.html')

@csrf_exempt
def order(request):
    obj={}
    print "request ajax------------------------"
    if request.GET:
        print "POST"
        sItem=request.GET.get('itemId')
        print "GET2 itemId="+sItem
        if sItem is not None:
            getobject=Food.objects.get(id=int(sItem))
            print getobject
            obj['id']=getobject.id
            obj['title']=getobject.title
            print "post2= "+str(obj)
            return render(request,'order.html',{"obj":obj})
        else:
            print "ER"
    return render_to_response("order.html",{'obj':obj})

js is like:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".orderbtn").click(function(){
        p=$(this).prop("id");
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"order/",
            data:{"itemId":p
                  //'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("{% csrf_token %}")
                 },
            success: function(data){
                $('#selected').html("data.title");
            }

        });

    });
});
```

All the code and the files are https://github.com/b10n1k/foodspot69.git

and the part of main.html where should display the data between div with id="menu_display".

```
<div id="selected" class="selected"></div >
```

So, I am not sure how must handle each view in this case. Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this and I post it without details to help others. In success function I added two parameters and now it looks:

```
success: function(data){
                $('#selected').html(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
```

I hope someone can give more details about because I dont know why they are required.